# android:state_activated for textviews in horizontalscrollview

Tags: android, xml, textview, horizontalscrollview

I have a horizontalscrollview containing many textviews that are added dynamically.  When I press on a textview, I would like its background to stay blue, until I click on another textview.  In a listview, you would use `android:state_activated`, but Android wont let me use it for a textview.  I have also tried setting the background in the onclicklistener, but it didnt work either.

How could I do this?

activity

```
public class HorizontaltextscrollerActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        LinearLayout menu = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.menu);

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            TextView t = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.text, null);
            t.setId(i);
            t.setText("item" + i);
            t.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hi " + v.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    v.setBackgroundColor(R.color.background_selected);
                }
            });

            menu.addView(t);
        }

    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/text_selector"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:clickable="true" >

</TextView>
```

text_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/selected" android:state_pressed="true"/>

</selector>
```

**EDIT1**

```
public class HorizontaltextscrollerActivity extends Activity {
    TextView[] t = new TextView[20];

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        LinearLayout menu = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.menu);

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            t[i] = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.text, null);

            t[i].setId(i);
            t[i].setText("item" + i);
            t[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hi " + v.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    t[v.getId()].setBackgroundColor(R.color.background_selected);
                }
            });

            menu.addView(t[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Soo actually, edit1 works when I use Color.WHITE instead of my own color variable.

Comment: Now my problem is how to get the textview to redraw their background when it is no longer selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an array of TextViews...

```
  TextView[] t=new TextView[20];
```

instead of this..

```
 TextView t = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.text, null);
```

use

```
 t[i] = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.text, null);
  t[i].setId(i);
 //similarly..
  t[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     for(int m=0;m<20;m++){
   if(m!=i){
    t[m].setBackgroundColor(R.color.putdefaultcolor here)
    }

     }
    t[i].setBackgroundColor(R.color.background_selected);

 .....
```

I think then it will work fine..

Comment: That didnt work either, I even took out the state_selector code out too. I'll update end of my post with code as EDIT1

Comment: Just note that to use custom colors, use `setBackgroundResource`